# Applying a Python script to a time series in blocks of 30 days at a time

Tags: python, time, window, subset, series

I have a script that I can apply to a large time series dataset in one go but I want to see if the results change subtly over time so I need to divide my time series into windows of 30 days and run the script for each block of 30 days over the whole period. A sample of my data looks like this with 24 points per day:

```
Date & time          B        C         S1      S2      S3
20/10/2015 00:00    1024.7  228.566111  2.672   2.742   4.508
20/10/2015 01:00    1024.5  65.740034   2.683   2.7535  4.509
20/10/2015 02:00    1024.6  -91.845869  2.6925  2.763   4.509
20/10/2015 03:00    1024.5  -222.368074 2.664   2.764   4.512
20/10/2015 04:00    1024.8  -306.697572 2.6615  2.763   4.5135
```

New to Python, I have searched this site, the pandas documentation, youtube videos and a number of tutorials but no luck. I had thought it was the rolling function but discovered this just worked for averaging the month's data (I want to apply the script to all the whole month). I then tried subsampling the data by the time stamp using :

```
file.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(file.Date_time,format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M') 
file.index = file.Timestamp
```

But that just gave me errors, as did:

```
monthy = file.resample('M')
```

The reason is I don't know much Python so I don't know what function I am looking for. Can anyone either help me or point me in the right direction of what function I need to be researching to do this? I am willing to do the research, just don't know what to search for and have run out of ideas. So far searches have included, resample, subsample, window, rolling, time frame, section and selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using normal for loop.
I am assuming you are using DataFrame for this data in your code.

```
#sample file
df = pd.read_excel('yourfile.xlsx')

#lets say your function name is myfunct(dataframe)

r = int(df.shape[0]/(30*24))
for i in range(r):
    temp = df.iloc[i:i+30*24,:]
    myfunct(temp)
#for remaing data that at the end
temp = df.iloc[r*30*24:,:]
myfunct(temp)
```

This should work fine.
let me know if something is ambiguous in the code.